# How to test if variable in php isset

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I am having a form with name, radios and email.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" role="form">
    <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="NAME">
    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL(optional)">

    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="male">Male
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="female">Female
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="gender" value="other">Other
    ...
```

To test whether name, email or radios are filled in, i use `isset`

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo 'name isset';
}
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    echo 'email isset';
}
if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
    echo 'gender isset';
}
```

What i don't understand: even when i leave the fields empty, it outputs the 2 echo's from the `name` and `email` loop, but NOT the `gender` loop.

Can someone explain me why the return values of name and email are TRUE even when i leave the fields empty and submit?
And why, if i do not click any of the radios, this return value is FALSE? ( `echo 'gender isset';` is not outputted!)

Comment: Empty fields just mean `""` empty input strings, not their absence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you leave the fields empty, they send an empty string to the server. Meaning the `$_POST['name']` will contain empty string `''`

Function `isset` checks if the value exists and is different from `null`. In your case empty string is different from `null` and exists.

You can use `empty` instead and it will work.

For example:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo 'name isset';
}
```

As for the radios - they are not sent, if none are selected. That's why `isset` works there.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I made a mistake by thinking that `''` is the same as `NULL`. Now i understand the issue!